# NetBeans not able to include files

Tags: setup, ide, netbeans, c++

- IDE: [NetBeans 6.8](http://www.netbeans.org/)
- OS: [Fedora 12](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_12_tour)

I have been having this problem for a long time now. NetBeans is almost impossible to use with C/C++, maybe because it was not made for it in first place.

Anyways what happens is this: I have this setup for C/C++

[image]

But, the programs are displayed like this:

[image]

It is not able to find any header file!!
I know it is a C++ program, the same thing happens with `#include <cstdio>`. As a result, it is not able to find the definition of `printf` and fails.

Same thing happens with a `.c` file.

Also, gcc works fine from the command line.

---

the problem exists still:

```
$ find / -name stdlib.h
/usr/include/bits/stdlib.h
/usr/include/c++/4.4.3/tr1/stdlib.h
/usr/include/stdlib.h
/usr/share/syslinux/com32/include/stdlib.h
/usr/arm-gp2x-linux/include/stdlib.h
```

[image]

**Did someone face this problem before?
What do I need to do to make this work?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should go on the tab "Code Assistance" and check the include paths. Happened to me that the paths referenced something like

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.3/include
```

but i upgraded to gcc 4.4, so i had to change that to

```
/usr/lib/gcc/i486-linux-gnu/4.4/include
```

hope that helps

**EDIT**

Seems from your screenshots that Netbeans doesn't look in all your include paths.
Please make sure that all your include paths are contemplated under "Code Assistance"

Comment: I tried that. not working still. I've added screenshots in the question. Please have a look. thanks!

Comment: @eSKay: you said that gcc compiles fine from the command line. Does it compile directly from netbeans too? Try compiling with full debug info and choose "reparse project" from CodeAssistance menu. Some times this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with NB 6.9 and solved by updating all my C++ plugin's (Tools > Plugin).

Answer (score 0):

Mine works. These are my settings:

In Options -> C/C++ -> Code Assistance Tab -> C compiler tab ->

I have the following in the "include directories"

```
/usr/local/include
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.4.3/include-fixed
/usr/include
```

The last one `/usr/include` is the one that should have stdio.h and stdlib.h.

I was able to get the C++ code assistance to work by adding `/usr/include/c++/4.4.3` in the c++ code assistance tab.

Edit: Your find command seems to have found all the relevant directories. Looks like you might just have to add them to the code assistance tab.

Comment: How to include directories and it's subdirectories at once?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Netbeans IDE 7.3 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, and I solved by removing this line

```
/usr/local/include
```

in Options -> C/C++ -> Code Assistance Tab -> C compiler tab

and Options -> C/C++ -> Code Assistance Tab -> C++ compiler tab

in this directory I dont have any header file.

I hope can help.

Comment: Its important to note that there are 2 tabs (as Walter specified). Be sure the "C++ complier" tab has the include directories. Try to build your project. Most of the warnings/errors may be cleared after that.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem with NetBeans 7.2.1. In fact when I created a C/C++ project, the main file was in .C extension (main.c).

I just select extension cpp instead and it works.

Answer (score 0):

I added /usr/include/c++/4.8/ to the include directories and it works.